# Integral inequality $\int_{B}\|\nabla f\|^2 \ge \frac14 \int_{B} \left( \|x\|^2+\|x\|^{-2}-4 \right)f(x)^2 dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R})$ , and $\text{supp} f$ is compact. Let $B$ be the unit ball. Prove the following inequalities
> $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\|\nabla f\|^2 \ge  \frac14 \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{f(x)^2}{\|x\|^2}dx$$
>
> $$\int_{B}\|\nabla f\|^2 \ge  \frac14 \int_{B} \left( \|x\|^2+\|x\|^{-2}-4 \right)f(x)^2dx$$

**My attempt**

I know that

$$\int_{\Omega}\|\nabla f\|^2=\int_{\partial\Omega}f\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}ds-\int_{\Omega}f \Delta f\,dx$$

But this formula doesn't seem to give us any useful guidance. The terms $\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}$ and $\Delta f$ are hard to evaluate unless we have more conditions.

Any hints? Thanks in advance!